# Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'bird.measurements' doesn't exist

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot and Hibernate project. When I try to build it I get errors related to creating (and sometimes dropping) the tables - even though the tables are created.

`Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'bird.measurements' doesn't exist`

Gradle is the build tool and I am using Intellij 2023 Ultimate.

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=secret
spring.datasource.driver-class-name =com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql: true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.sql.init.mode=always

spring.sql.init.platform=all
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL8SpatialDialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false
spring.devtools.restart.enabled=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.util.CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNamingStrategy
```

**entity**

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@DiscriminatorValue("MICROCHIP")
public class Microchip extends Task {
    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotEmpty(message = "Name must not be null or empty")
    private String code;
    @JoinColumn(name ="date_instered")
    private LocalDate dateInserted;
}
```

I get these errors on many of my entities:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate tries to drop all the tables before creating them. If anything doesn't exist it generates the error which is logged and not fatal.

If you don't change the schema and boot-run again there is no error.